# Disappearing Toggle Button macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have simple Excel macro, for ToggleButton:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
Dim xAddress As String
xAddress = "L:R"
If ToggleButton1.Value Then
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = True
Else
    Application.ActiveSheet.Columns(xAddress).Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

When I upload this to OneDrive and download, macro disappear.

[image]

I have just ToggleButton definition, so it doesn't work.

How I can store this macro permanently?

Comment: Have you saved it with ".xlsm" or ".xlsb" expansion?

Comment: As .xlsx expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your file as ".xlsm" or ".xlsb" file, and everything should be fine.